# Error: No module named 'pymem.process'; 'pymem' is not a package

Tags: python

I am trying to learn how to use pymem in Python.
I have tried to make two different programs according to two tutorials I have seen but I always get the same error when I try to run the code.

I have this:

```
from pymem import Pymem

pm = pymem("ac_client.exe")

health = pm.read_int(0x007B43F4)

print ("Health: ", health)
```

But when I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\N\Desktop\PYTHON\pymem\pymem2.py", line 1, in <module>    
    from pymem import Pymem
  File "c:\Users\N\Desktop\PYTHON\pymem\pymem.py", line 4, in <module>     
    from pymem.process import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymem.process'; 'pymem' is not a package
```

I have `pymem` installed in it's latest version from Visual Studio Code. And in the videos I've seen (one is from a few months ago) they have the same code as me.

Comment: Is that literally your code?  Because in the current version, the object is capitalized:   `from pymem import Pymem`.

Comment: I just edited the question again with the full code (it should work though it's a very simple thing).
I have another longer and more complete code but I think this one understands the question. The person I see the tutorial works for him having exactly the same thing as me.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback not just the last line of it (so we can determine what line of your code is causing the problem).

Comment: The documentation has it capitalized like I showed:  https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: You have this in a folder called `pymem`.  Why?  If that's the same folder as the `pymem` module, then that doesn't work.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Was just about to ask the same thing — another common problem here — and the `in <module>` in the stacktrace proves it.

Comment: codeame: Rename your script file and try to run it again.

Comment: You are right, I changed the folder to a completely different name and renamed the file .py and moved it to this folder (before I used one folder for many files, I don't know if this is bad)
For now it seems to work!
Thank you very much to both.
So I can't name the files with this kind of name right?

Answer (score 0):

You have a file named `pymem.py` that's mentioned in the exception message (specifically `c:\Users\N\Desktop\PYTHON\pymem\pymem.py`). This locally written `pymem` module is shadowing the `pymem` package you've installed elsewhere (`python\python310\lib\site-packages` according to one of your comments, though that path is not complete).

You need to rename your `pymem.py` file to something else if you want to be able to use the package.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't have it installed, try going into cmd, Terminal or whatever and type `pip install pymem`.

`pip` should install the package for you and you should be good.

Comment: I have it installed, I just checked: 
Requirement already satisfied: pymem in... python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.8.5)

Comment: If he didn't have it installed, there would be an immediate error on the `from pymem import pymem` line.

Comment: @codeame: You may have to do something to make Visual Studio Code aware that it's installed — a fairly common problem here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).